# Embed (create) an interactive Python shell inside a Python program

Tags: python

Is it possible to start an interactive Python shell inside a Python program?

I want to use such an interactive Python shell (which is running *inside* my program's execution) to inspect some program-internal variables.

Comment: You could use pdb, IDE debuggers, or `print` for that.

Answer (score 76):

The [code](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module provides an interactive console:

```
import readline # optional, will allow Up/Down/History in the console
import code
variables = globals().copy()
variables.update(locals())
shell = code.InteractiveConsole(variables)
shell.interact()
```

Comment: Note that `vars` is a built-in function. Also, in Python 3.5+, you can create a "compound" dictionary from two existing dictionaries using dict expansion: `variables = {**globals(), **locals()}`.

Comment: @kyrill Fixed the former point. Since there still is a significant number of Python<3.5 users, I'll keep the dictionary compounding as is for now.

Comment: is it possible to wrap or enclose the interactiveconsole within a widget in PyQt5?

Comment: @Ash That sounds like a great question (although you probably only need *an* interactive console, not necessarily this specific module). Go ahead and [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: @phihag: `readline` doesen't seems to exist anymore. Is the up/down/history feature still avaiable through some standard library?

Comment: @Skandix `readline` [exists just fine even in the cutting-edge Python](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/readline.html). If it fails to import, please ask a new question (and maybe point me to it).

Comment: is there a command I can use in the shell to return execution to the program?

Comment: @Alfie As in any other shell, you can press `Ctrl`+`D` to end the shell.

Comment: @Alfie If you want to do it on Windows, use `Ctrl`+`Z` and `Enter` instead of `Ctrl`+`D`.

Answer (score 21):

In ipython 0.13+ you need to do this:

```
from IPython import embed

embed()
```

Comment: For a really long time I had been using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. I have found the ultimate tool `embed()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've had this code for a long time, I hope you can put it to use.

To inspect/use variables, just put them into the current namespace. As an example, I can access `var1` and `var2` from the command line.

```
var1 = 5
var2 = "Mike"
# Credit to effbot.org/librarybook/code.htm for loading variables into current namespace
def keyboard(banner=None):
    import code, sys

    # use exception trick to pick up the current frame
    try:
        raise None
    except:
        frame = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back

    # evaluate commands in current namespace
    namespace = frame.f_globals.copy()
    namespace.update(frame.f_locals)

    code.interact(banner=banner, local=namespace)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  keyboard()
```

**However** if you wanted to strictly debug your application, I'd **highly** suggest using an IDE or [pdb(python debugger)](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 5):

Using IPython you just have to call:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed; IPShellEmbed()()
```

Comment: In fact, you should use `import IPython; IPython.embed();`. See [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/286).

Comment: Yeah that is what I use today too, 3 years later =)

Answer (score 1):

Another trick (besides the ones already suggested) is opening an interactive shell and importing your (perhaps modified) python script. Upon importing, most of the variables, functions, classes and so on (depending on how the whole thing is prepared) are available, and you could even create objects interactively from command line. So, if you have a `test.py` file, you could open Idle or other shell, and type `import test` (if it is in current working directory).

Comment: A similar approach that would place the script's globals in the global namespace instead of a module namespace: `exec(open("test.py").read())`